# Check for width before executing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JS script that needs to make some computations based on a width of an element. Unfortunately this element can be delayed loading pending other third-party libraries. So I thought I need to add another function that will check for width and if it's not available, wait a bit and check again. Once it's available, fire the other function that needs that width value.

```
function checkIfReady() {
    var em_width = $("#myEm").width();
    if (em_width < 10) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            checkIfReady();
        }, 2000);
    } else {
        checkIfReady(em_width);
    }
}
```

Am I overcomplicating this and if yes, is there a better solution?

Comment: *"this element can be delayed loading pending other third-party libraries"* - do you mean that it's *loading* or that is being  *added* at a later time by third party libraries?

Comment: It's loading with my scripts, however, some third libraries can cause delay rendering the page, which must be fully rendered before I can get exact width of the needed element.

Comment: So you have 2 functions of checkIfReady one with no argument checking the width and one with 1 arguments which is executed once the width is ready to set? If yes you are doing it right and there is no less complicated way to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not look overcomplicated for me.

One note if that element does not exist yet, then `em_width < 10` returns false, so maybe better to check `if (!em_width)` - that way you'll check both cases:

- for `null`, in case if it does not exist yet;
- for `0`, in case if it exists but didn't load any content.

Actually, I often use a similar approach waiting for the element width:

```
async myMethod() {
    while (!$('#myEm').width()) {
      await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 100))
    }
    doYourComputations();
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: No, plain JS/ES6 code, with the only framework jQuery (as OP asked). If you want to have it without jQuery, with the only javascript, change the second line of the code above to the following:
`while (!document.querySelector('#myEm').clientWidth) {`